# jQuery - Set background color from multiple buttons' inner text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying change the background color from multiple buttons based of their inner text using jQuery. It was easy enough to do with straight javascript using a for loop but I can't figure out how to do the same thing in jQuery.

Here's where I'm at:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $(body).css('background-color', "$('button').text()");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting it to a string, not the value of the text. And you want to use `this` to get a reference to the element that was clicked. Just using `$("button")` would return the text of the first button.

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $(body).css('background-color', $(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `body` is an element, so either use `document.body`, or use `"body"` to select it.
2. As `this` should be the button you clicked, just wrap it with jquery and call `.text()` on it. `$(body).css('background-color', "$('button').text()");` will try to set the string `"$('button').text()"` to `background-color`, jquery won't try to parse it and get the value from it for you.

```js
$('button').click(function(){
    $('body').css('background-color', $(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>red</button>
<button>blue</button>
```